# Adding custom fields and types in nutch elastic indexer

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, nutch

I was running test runs on nutch elastic indexer.I would like to add some custom fields and custom typenames(instead of "doc") that can be given as arguments to the indexing job. I understand **`NutchDocument`** is the class which is responsible for setting field names and metadata but couldn't figure out where nutch create instance of this and sets values. Or Is there any other way for this. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need (to add new fields into the ES index) is to write a custom indexing filter (supposing that the value of the field you want to add is already being extracted from the content by some parsing filter, otherwise you'll need both a parse filter and the indexing filter).

[image: nutch indexing plugin] In the previous image you can see a simple diagram on how the indexing filters work in Nutch. Perhaps [this post](https://jorgelbg.wordpress.com/2014/08/30/indexing-inlinks-and-outlinks-with-nutch-1-x/) would help you. Bottom line is that you add fields into the `NutchDocument` class in the indexing filter which implements the `IndexingFilter` interface. This fields that you add into `NutchDocument` are automatically translated into your indexing backend (Solr/ES) by the corresponding plugin.

As for chaning the `type` field you'll need to extract/add a `type` field into the `NutchDocument` class, take a look at https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/indexer-elastic/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexwriter/elastic/ElasticIndexWriter.java#L169-L171. `"doc"` is the default type provided if you can't provide one. So in your custom indexing filter you'll add you logic to dynamically set the `type` field and this will be used by the `ElasticIndexWriter` during the indexing phase.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) I have one more query. Am using nutch REST api to invoke crawl actions. So is there anyway to pass some options as arguments to indexing action and then index based on that arguments ? I didn't see any option to retrieve args on indexing filter.

Comment: Anything on this ?

Comment: Hi @Sachin could you elaborate a bit more? The general answer I think is that you can't pass any info into the indexing action. In your seed file you can add custom metadata to your seed file but there is no logic on how the indexer should react to this info (other than indexing). You could write your own for instance take a look at https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/mimetype-filter/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/filter/MimeTypeIndexingFilter.java that use the detected mime type to decide if the doc should be indexed or not.

Comment: Just one more thing, as a general approach if your custom `IndexingFilter` returns `null` (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/IndexingFilter.java#L40-L61) on the `filter` method then the document will be ignored/skipped from indexing

Comment: Hi @Jorge , my requirement is to pass any extra information that can be added to index. For eg : an argument to indexer like published_date: 21/12/2012 that can be added to index.

Comment: But this `published_date` field from where is coming? Is something that you extract from the text of the webpage? Or the date that the document is being indexed?, for instance?

Comment: For instance I have extracted published_date,author etc from a feed using some feed parser library. Now I want to use nutch to crawl a feed link and add this already extracted info to index. Since am using nutch rest api,can I supply this info as args in REST call?

Comment: No, at the moment you can't supply this info using an API REST call. But if you're extracting the date from somewhere outside of Nutch, you could update the document directly into Solr. But my recommendation is to try and extract the info from the parsed content using a `HtmlParseFilter` and that way you use the mechanism provided with Nutch. Downside you'll need to customize Nutch, also why you don't use the feed plugin that comes with Nutch?

Comment: Thanks for the info Luis. I didn't check the feed plugin provided by nutch. So can I give a RSS feed url to nutch so that it will read and fetch all the urls provided in feed ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the feed plugin will index the fields that are found in the RSS feed as separated documents in ES, but it will not fetch the content (so you'll only get the summary) but if you use the `parse-tika` plugin the URLs found in the feed will be treated as outlinks and fetched in subsequent step.

Comment: Ok. I didn't knew that. Thanks for the info :)